# How to find the roots of a cubic polynomial?

Tags: roots, cubics

All of the examples on the internet I could find are made so that you can somehow make the cubic equation into a first degree polynomial multiplied by a second degree polynomial. But what if you can't do that?

For example, how would you find the roots of the following equation:

**$x^3+7x^2+16x+12=0$**

I know the roots are **$-2$, $-2$ and $-3$** but don't know how to get them.
If I somehow guess them, is there a way to tell which one is the double root?

Comment: One uses the Rational Root Theorem to determine candidate roots.

Comment: Two things to look into: (1) the rational root theorem; (2) polynomial long division.

Comment: Also, suppose you know that $x=-2$ and $x=3$ are the only roots, so you know that one of them is a double root. You can plug those into $f'(x)$; if you get $f'(x)=0$, then $x$ is a double root.

Comment: You need to first search online, e.g. googling "How to find solutions to cubic polynomials", after you'll reach a page that informs you of the rational root theorem, which you could further search on Wikipedia....  Hence it is appropriate to downvote the question because it shows no research.  You are expect to make efforts to contribute to the solution of your question.

Comment: Yet another example of trying to avoid dispensing with elegance  and "getting down in the mud".  Googling: "wikipedia cubic equation" leads to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), which is **comprehensive**.  Who cares if it is messy - the problem is solved.

Comment: Descartes' Rule of Signs implies that any real root of the given polynomial is negative, which reduces by half the set of candidate roots produced by the Rational Root Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Start out by checking the positive and negative factors of 12. Once you find one factor that makes the polynomial equal to zero, say $x = -2$, divide the polynomial by the corresponding factor $x+2$. You can use synthetic division or long division. Once you do that you get the quadratic factor $x^2+5x+6$. Factor the quadratic to get $(x+2)(x+3)$, therefore:$$x^3+7x^2+16x+12=(x+2)(x+2)(x+3)=0$$ This means $x = -2$, $-2$, and $-3$ as you pointed out but now you can see clearly that one factor repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Factorize as follows
$$x^3+7x^2+16x+12\\
=(x^3+7x^2+12x)+(4x+12)\\
=x(x+4)(x+3)+4(x+3)\\
=(x+3)(x^2+4x+4)
$$

Comment: What you say is true, but I doubt it provides a useful solution.  The OP is likely interested in finding roots,  and once we know them, of course the factors are also found.

Answer (score 0):

While there is a rather nice test for whether a cubic polynomial has a *triple* zero by inspecting its coefficients (it will even tell us directly the value of that root), there is not *anywhere near* as simple a method for testing for a double zero by using the coefficients.  (It can be managed, but the calculations do not just require basic arithmetic.)

We can produce a straightforward method of testing with the coefficients if we *suspect* that a double zero is present.  We would write for the polynomial $ \ ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \ = \ a · (x - r)^2 · (x - s) \ \ , $ with $ \ r \ $ being the double zero and $ \ s \ $ being the other (real) zero.  This alone is not especially helpful, but we could express the "singleton" zero as $ \ s = \sigma · r \ \ . $  This then gives us
$$ a · (x - r)^2 · (x \ - \ \sigma · r) \ \ = \ \ a · ( x^3 \ - \ [ \ 2r \ + \ \sigma · r \ ]· x^2 \ + \ [ \ r^2 \ + \ 2·\sigma·r^2 \ ]·x \ - \ \sigma·r^3 \ \ . $$

The relation among the coefficients will thus be
$$ \frac{b}{a} \ = \  -r · (\sigma \ + \ 2) \ \ , \ \ \frac{c}{a} \ = \  r^2 · (1 \ + \ 2·\sigma) \ \ , \ \ \frac{d}{a} \ = \  -\sigma · r^3 \ \ . $$

This can be helpful for integer and "reasonably simple" rational coefficients.  For your example polynomial $ \ x^3 + 7x^2 + 16x + 12 \ \ , $ the fact that the constant coefficient can be factored as $ \ 12 = 2^2 · 3 \ $ might lead us to check for a double zero.  We could have either $ \ \frac{d}{a} \ = \  12 \ = \ - \ 2^2 · (-3) \ \ $ or $ \ -(-2)^2 · (-3) \ \ . $  The Rule of Signs  *will* tell us which of the two factorizations would be the one to try, but we will see that this test also leaves no sign ambiguity:

$$  \mathbf{r = 2 \ , \ \sigma = -\frac32 \ \ :} \quad  \frac{b}{a} \ = \  -2 · \left(-\frac32 \ + \ 2 \right) \  =  \ -1  \ \ , \ \ \frac{c}{a} \ = \  2^2 · \left(1 \ + \ 2·\left[-\frac32 \right] \right) \  =  \  -8 \ \ ;  $$
$$  \mathbf{r = -2 \ , \ \sigma = \frac32 \ \ :} \quad  \frac{b}{a} \ = \  2 · \left(\frac32 \ + \ 2 \right) \  =  \ 7  \ \ , \ \ \frac{c}{a} \ = \  (-2)^2 · \left(1 \ + \ 2·\frac32  \right) \  = \   16 \ \ .  $$

Hence, the zeroes are $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ [\text{multiplicity} \ 2] \ , \ -3 \ \ $ or $ \ x^3 + 7x^2 + 16x + 12 \ = \ (x + 2)^2 · (x \ + \ \frac32 · 2) \ = \ (x + 2)^2 · (x  +  3) \ \ . $

As an additional demonstration, we could attempt to solve in this manner $ \ 9x^3 + 3x^2 - 56x + 48 \ = \ 0  \ : $

$$ \frac{d}{a} \ = \  \frac{48}{9} \  = \  \frac{16}{3} \ = \ - \left(\frac43 \right)^2 · (-3) \ \ \ [?]  $$
(the Rule of Signs tells us there would be one negative zero and two positive real zeroes) so we will want to check $ \  r = \frac43 \ , \ \sigma = -\frac94 \ \ : $

$$ \rightarrow \ \     \frac{b}{a} \ = \  -\frac43 · \left(-\frac94 \ + \ 2 \right) \  =  \ \frac13  \ \ , \ \ \frac{c}{a} \ = \  \left(\frac43 \right)^2 · \left(1 \ + \ 2·\left[-\frac94 \right] \right) \  =  \  -\frac{56}{9} \ \ .  $$

We *do* have $ \ b = \frac93 = 3 \ $ and $ \ c = -56 \ \ , $ which permits us to conclude that
$$    9x^3 + 3x^2 - 56x + 48 \ \ = \ \ 9 · \left( x - \frac43 \right)^2 · \ (x + 3 ) \ \ . $$

Naturally, if this coefficient test indicates that we do not have a double zero, we will need to "fall back" to more elaborate methods to determine the zeroes.